# Resharper: "some control paths may leak this resource acquisition" c++

Tags: c++, resharper

Resharper tells me "some control paths may leak this resource acquisition" as an advice. What it can mean?

Comment: it means that not all code paths result in resources being freed after being allocated (such as memory, file handles, etc)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means that you have acquired a resource such as memory or an operating system handle and there is a path in your program that will not free this resource.

To provide any help for this case, you would need to actually post the code that triggered the warning.

Generally speaking, look into [RAII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) to handle this better.